# Range of values which satisfy an equation

Tags: equation-solving

I have an equation in two variables and I am trying to find if there exists some range where the equation is satisfied. Having tried a few methods I am not yet sure if I can say that no such range exists or simply that I can't find it.

Here is the equation :

```
Binomial[n,2]*(3.97887*10^-10 Cos[200 k ArcSinh[50/k]])/Sqrt[1 + 2500/k^2] = -0.00003
```

Kindly provide some suggestions.

Edit :

If it is somehow helpful then I am looking for extremely high values of `n` (could be `10^23` order) which can satisfy this equation with some range of `k`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such great n try to rescale your equation!

Try `n->Exp[logn],k->Exp[-logk]` with scaled variables `logk,logn`:

```
eq = (Binomial[n, 2]*(3.97887*10^-10 Cos[200 k ArcSinh[50/k]])/Sqrt[1 + 2500/k^2] == -0.00003 // Rationalize) /. {n -> Exp[logn], k -> Exp[-logk]}

soln[logk_] :=logn /. NSolve[{(1.9894350000000002`*^-10 E^logn (-1 + E^logn) Cos[200 E^-logk ArcSinh[50 E^logk]])/Sqrt[1 + 2500 E^(2 logk)] == -(3/100000), -25 < logn < 25}, logn, Reals] [[1]]
```

This gives

```
Plot[soln[logk], {logk, 0, .1},AxesLabel-> {"Log[k]","Log[n]"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Just a little more clarification needed. `ReplaceAll` gives an error : `ReplaceAll::reps: {(1.98944*10^-10 E^logn (-1+E^logn) Cos[200 E^-logk ArcSinh[50 Power[<<2>>]]])/Sqrt[1+2500 E^Times[<<2>>]]==-(3/100000),-25<logn<25} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing.` Given this error, is the plot okay? Also, would you say that `n` and `k` don't really have any solutions? Given the almost tangent curves or zeroes?

Comment: Where does this error come from? I retested my code with fresh kernel, seems to be ok.

Comment: It's showing up on my Mathematica 11.0

Comment: It occurs when you try to plot? Does a single evaluation `soln[.1] (*7.97209*)` evaluate? My version is Mathematica 12.

Comment: Now, it's `7.97209` without any error

Comment: No idea, perhaps `Plot[Evaluate[soln[logk] ],...]`works?

Comment: Have you taken here the range of `logn` to be `-25 to 25`? Also, why do you rationalise?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107157/discussion-between-nitin-and-ulrich-neumann).

Comment: The range restriction is considered inside `soln…]` . `Rationalize` is good praxis in finding analytic solutions.